# Customising an optimiser while keeping high level tf.keras.fit() API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, optimization

I am trying a customised gradient descent ([PCGrad](https://github.com/tianheyu927/PCGrad)) on multi-tasking deep learning network. Unfortunately the implementation requires low level tf API. My current model is written in high level API using tf.keras with `fit()` and `compile()`. Here is a simple toy example

```
model_input = Input(shape=(100))
model_output_0 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(model_input)
model_output_1 = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(model_input)

toy_model = Model(inputs=[model_input],outputs=[model_output_0, model_output_1])

toy_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

toy_model.fit([training_X, y_label_0, y_label_1],
      epochs=10,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=([validation_X],[val_y_label_0, val_y_label_1]), 
      batch_size=32
      )
```

I am hoping to preserve as much of the high level API as possible so I do not have to write a [low-level loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch). In order to successfully assimilate this change in optimiser to my high level API, I have encountered 2 problems as following:

From the PCGrad Github repository, I know that I will need a list of all the losses. Suppose I am using binary crossentropy to compute my losses (from a 2-headed multi-tasking model), I expect the list to look like this:

```
bce_func = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
losses = [bce_func(y_true_0,model_output_0), bce_func(y_true_1,model_output_1)]
```

However, I am unsure how I can 'link' `y_true_0`, `y_true_1` to the ground truth specified in `fit()`.

Following that, I have to connect the optimiser to the `compile()` function which requires its own `loss` argument. Perhaps it will look something like this:

```
optim = PCGrad(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())    
toy_model.compile(optimizer=optim(), loss=losses)
```

Intuitively, I think this is probably not possible and I will probably have to write the training loop manually. But in case any expert out here does have an idea, I would greatly appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Comment: You can [customize what happens in fit()](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/)

Comment: @Lescurel thank you very much for the suggestion. I looked into it and I would have to customise what happens in compile() as well. On top of that the original author of the paper used tf1 while we are now on tf2 and therefore I am using the gradienttape api. Having to translate tf1 to tf2 while working in a low level api has proven to be too difficult for me after 2 days of trying so I have decided to use pytorch instead where there are [kind individuals out there who have implemented the method already](https://github.com/WeiChengTseng/Pytorch-PCGrad). Thank you nonetheless for your help!